# Android Dokka - Only generate docs for my code and skip everything else

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-dokka, kdoc

I'm using `Dokka v0.9.17` for Android. When I run `./gradlew dokka` it generates the docs but it include so many packages that I don't care about like `android.support.fragment` and packages for all the third party libraries. How can I tell Dokka to only generate doc for my code?

How can I remove Dagger `_Factory` files from the doc?

My configuration is like this

```
dokka {
    moduleName = 'app'
    outputFormat = 'html'
    outputDirectory = "$buildDir/javadoc"
    includeNonPublic = true
    skipEmptyPackages = true
    noStdlibLink = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Paragones had the correct answer to a different so issue

https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/issues/258

namely you need to add this task and modify it to only delete the stuff you want deleted:

```
task deleteUnusedDokkaAssets(type: Delete) {
  file("$rootDir/docs").listFiles().each {        
    if(it.name.contains("android.R")) project.delete it
    if(it.name.contains("android.support")) project.delete it
    if(it.name.contains("com.google")) project.delete it  
    if(it.name.contains("com.crashlytics")) project.delete it
  }
}
```

note you will not need the android.R line with the updated version of dokka